# Why records are not getting saved in Access DB Table (2nd Issue)? Need Guidance

Tags: database, ms-access

Now I have a working SQL code that inserts records into my database table(creates runtime) and the code is below...

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT NewMember.ApplicantName, NewMember.ApplicationNo, NewMember.ProcessingFee, NewMember.IntroducerName, NewMember.IntroducerCode, NewMember.JoiningDate, NewCustomer.ApplicationNo, NewCustomer.PlanName, NewCustomer.AccountNo, NewCustomer.InvestmentAmount, NewCustomer.ProcessingFees, NewCustomer.OpeningDate, Deposit.Date, Deposit.InvestmentAmount Into DDTable  FROM NewMember, NewCustomer, Deposit WHERE NewMember.JoiningDate = NewCustomer.OpeningDate AND NewCustomer.OpeningDate = Deposit.Date;", con)
```

But the recent problem is that, when I am using DateTimePicker to select any date then records are not getting saved. Yet the codes are not showing any error! Any Idea, Any Help?

@Christian Specht,

Thanks but Where clause is working well in my first posted code and in which it's not working is here

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT NewMember.ApplicantName, (NewMember.ApplicationNo)As MemberApplicationNo, NewMember.ProcessingFee, NewMember.IntroducerName, NewMember.IntroducerCode, NewMember.JoiningDate, NewCustomer.ApplicationNo, NewCustomer.PlanName, NewCustomer.AccountNo, NewCustomer.InvestmentAmount, NewCustomer.ProcessingFees, NewCustomer.OpeningDate, Deposit.Date, (Deposit.InvestmentAmount) As Renewal Into DDTable FROM NewMember, NewCustomer, Deposit WHERE (NewMember.JoiningDate = #" & dtpDates.Text & "#)= (NewCustomer.OpeningDate = #" & dtpDates.Text & "#) And NewCustomer.OpeningDate = (Deposit.Date =#" & dtpDates.Text & "#);", con)
```

---

Success Msg but Data not getting saved in database (code):

```
If (con.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then con.Open()
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT NewMember.ApplicantName, (NewMember.ApplicationNo)As MemberApplicationNo, NewMember.ProcessingFee, NewMember.IntroducerName, NewMember.IntroducerCode, NewMember.JoiningDate, NewCustomer.ApplicationNo, NewCustomer.PlanName, NewCustomer.AccountNo, NewCustomer.InvestmentAmount, NewCustomer.ProcessingFees, NewCustomer.OpeningDate, Deposit.Date, (Deposit.InvestmentAmount) As Renewal Into DDTable FROM NewMember, NewCustomer, Deposit WHERE (NewMember.JoiningDate = #" & dtpDates.Text & "#)= (NewCustomer.OpeningDate = #" & dtpDates.Text & "#) And NewCustomer.OpeningDate = (Deposit.Date =#" & dtpDates.Text & "#);", con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("Saved Successfully! ", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
con.Close()
```

---

### Is it because, I am trying to fetch results = DateTimePicker.value,  where time is not mentioned and by default the value is YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.000. Do I need to use any ‘> or <’ sign!? But I need where Date is only equal to user picked date.

@all: Here is the Answer

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT NewMember.ApplicantName, (NewMember.ApplicationNo)As MemberApplicationNo, NewMember.ProcessingFee, NewMember.IntroducerName, NewMember.IntroducerCode, NewMember.JoiningDate, NewCustomer.ApplicationNo, NewCustomer.PlanName, NewCustomer.AccountNo, NewCustomer.InvestmentAmount, NewCustomer.ProcessingFees, NewCustomer.OpeningDate, Deposit.Date, (Deposit.InvestmentAmount) As Renewal Into DDTable FROM NewMember, NewCustomer, Deposit WHERE NewMember.JoiningDate = NewCustomer.OpeningDate And NewCustomer.OpeningDate = Deposit.Date And Deposit.Date >= #" & A & "#", con)
```

A is my datetimepicker.value

Comment: Your query does not show any use of an outside parameter to limit by date.  Can you show that syntax?

Comment: My 2nd code gives success msg but records are getting saved in database!

Comment: Okay, now show us what the SQL looks like after you join together the strings and the date.text.  The answer to your problem will be there.

Comment: @MoheshBhattacharjee: Larry is right. Again, you could try to output the joined string, omit the `Into DDTable` part and try to run *that* directly in Access.

Comment: @ Christian Specht: I have done this and Access shows me the data (1 row), because conditions met.

Answer (score 0):

If the query runs without error, but doesn't insert anything into the table, then it probably doesn't return any results because of the `WHERE` clause.

Try running the query directly in the Access query editor without the `Into DDTable` part and see if it returns any results.